# Removing data from a merged datafile?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm in the early stages of learning how to use Pandas and have recently merged two files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import pandas as pd
fields = ['Title', 'Year', 'Length', 'Director']
X = pd.read_csv('Films.csv',skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
fields2 = ['Title', 'Year', 'Length', 'budget', 'rating', 'Action', 'Animation', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Documentary', 'Romance', 'Short']
Y = pd.read_csv('Movies.csv',skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields2, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
FilmMovies = pd.merge(X, Y, on=['Title'])
```

What I'm trying to do now is remove all instances of duplicate titles from this merged file as well as any instance where the budget is N/A. What command would I use to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
new_df = FilmMovies.drop_duplicates('Title').dropna(subset=['budget'])
```